# Implement the tree in java? not hard coded

Tags: java, list, dictionary, recursion, tree

There is a Tree implementation, which requires the correction and idea of how to implement the logic.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @param <T>
 */
class TreeNode<T> implements Iterable<TreeNode<T>> {

    private final List<TreeNode<T>> elementsIndex;
    public T data;
    public TreeNode<T> parent;
    public List<TreeNode<T>> children;

    /**
     * @param data
     */
    public TreeNode(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.children = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
        this.elementsIndex = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
        this.elementsIndex.add(this);
    }

    /**
     * @param depth
     * @return Indentation
     */
    private static String createIndent(int depth) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            sb.append('-');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @return parent
     */
    public boolean isRoot() {
        return parent == null;
    }

    /**
     * @return check the size of child
     */
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return children.size() == 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param child
     * @return child node
     */
    public TreeNode<T> addChild(T child) {
        TreeNode<T> childNode = new TreeNode<T>(child);
        childNode.parent = this;
        this.children.add(childNode);
        this.registerChildForSearch(childNode);
        return childNode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the depth of the level
     */
    public int getLevel() {
        if (this.isRoot())
            return 0;
        else
            return parent.getLevel() + 1;
    }

    /**
     * @param node
     */
    private void registerChildForSearch(TreeNode<T> node) {
        elementsIndex.add(node);
        if (parent != null)
            parent.registerChildForSearch(node);
    }

    /**
     * @param cmp
     * @return finds the element
     */
    public TreeNode<T> findTreeNode(Comparable<T> cmp) {
        for (TreeNode<T> element : this.elementsIndex) {
            T elData = element.data;
            if (cmp.compareTo(elData) == 0)
                return element;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the root
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data != null ? data.toString() : "[data null]";
    }

    /**
     * @return iterator
     */
    @Override
    public Iterator<TreeNode<T>> iterator() {
        TreeNodeIter<T> iter = new TreeNodeIter<T>(this);
        return iter;
    }

    /**
     * @param treeRoot
     * @param data
     * @return the data else null if not found
     */
    public TreeNode<T> search(TreeNode<T> treeRoot, T data) {

        Comparable<T> searchCriteria = new Comparable<T>() {
            @Override
            public int compareTo(Object treeData) {
                if (treeData == null)
                    return 1;
                boolean nodeOk = treeData.equals(data);
                return nodeOk ? 0 : 1;
            }
        };
        TreeNode<T> found = treeRoot.findTreeNode(searchCriteria);
        return found;
    }

    /**
     * @param treeRoot
     * @return the whole tree
     */
    public StringBuilder display(TreeNode<T> treeRoot) {
        StringBuilder print = new StringBuilder();
        print.append('\n');
        for (TreeNode<T> node : treeRoot) {
            String indent = createIndent(node.getLevel());
            print.append(indent + node.data);
            print.append("\n|");
        }
        if (print.length() > 0)
            print.deleteCharAt(print.length() - 1);
        return print;
    }

}

/**
 * @param <T>
 */
class TreeNodeIter<T> implements Iterator<TreeNode<T>> {

    private final TreeNode<T> treeNode;
    private final Iterator<TreeNode<T>> childrenCurNodeIter;
    private ProcessStages doNext;
    private TreeNode<T> next;
    private Iterator<TreeNode<T>> childrenSubNodeIter;

    /**
     * @param treeNode
     */
    public TreeNodeIter(TreeNode<T> treeNode) {
        this.treeNode = treeNode;
        this.doNext = ProcessStages.ProcessParent;
        this.childrenCurNodeIter = treeNode.children.iterator();
    }

    /**
     * @return true if there is nay element
     */
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {

        if (this.doNext == ProcessStages.ProcessParent) {
            this.next = this.treeNode;
            this.doNext = ProcessStages.ProcessChildCurNode;
            return true;
        }

        if (this.doNext == ProcessStages.ProcessChildCurNode) {
            if (childrenCurNodeIter.hasNext()) {
                TreeNode<T> childDirect = childrenCurNodeIter.next();
                childrenSubNodeIter = childDirect.iterator();
                this.doNext = ProcessStages.ProcessChildSubNode;
                return hasNext();
            } else {
                this.doNext = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (this.doNext == ProcessStages.ProcessChildSubNode) {
            if (childrenSubNodeIter.hasNext()) {
                this.next = childrenSubNodeIter.next();
                return true;
            } else {
                this.next = null;
                this.doNext = ProcessStages.ProcessChildCurNode;
                return hasNext();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return the next element
     */
    @Override
    public TreeNode<T> next() {
        return this.next;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    enum ProcessStages {
        ProcessParent,
        ProcessChildCurNode,
        ProcessChildSubNode
    }

}
```

**So, the issue is that I have the data something like this**

```
Gen
|-Test1
|--Mat
|-Test2
|--123
|---Child's Child
|----Child's Child's Child
|----2406
|-Test3
|--24
```

**But to implement that I have to hard code something like this**

```
public static TreeNode<String> getSet() {
    TreeNode<String> root = new TreeNode<String>("Gen");
    {
        TreeNode<String> node0 = root.addChild("Test1");
        {
            TreeNode<String> node00 = node0.addChild("Mat");
        }
        TreeNode<String> node1 = root.addChild("Test2");
        {
            TreeNode<String> node10 = node1.addChild("123");
            {
                TreeNode<String> node100 = node10.addChild("Child's Child");
                {
                    TreeNode<String> node1000 = node100.addChild("Child's Child's Child");
                    TreeNode<String> node1001 = node100.addChild("2406");
                }
            }
        }
        TreeNode<String> node2 = root.addChild("Test3");
        {
            TreeNode<String> node20 = node2.addChild("24");
        }
        
    }

    return root;
}
```

}

*On the top that I have the helper method called `getPartentChildPart()` method which is used to get the
Map<Parent, List> that is `Map<String,List<String>>`*

```
Gen
|-Test1
|--Mat
|-Test2
|--123
|---Child's Child
|----Child's Child's Child
|----2406
|-Test3
|--24
```

For example, if I gave `Gen` as the parameter to `getPartentChildPart()` then it will return

```
Map<Gen,<Test1,Test2,Test3>>
```

So far what I can achieve is this

```
    public void Build(Map<String, List<String>> ROOT)  {
        TreeNode<String> root = null;
        TreeNode<String> node = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> i : ROOT.entrySet()) {
            root = new TreeNode<>(i.getKey());
            for (String j : i.getValue())
            {
                node = root.addChild(j);
                parent = getPartentChildPart(j);
                Build(parent);
            }
            System.out.println("Root"+root.display(root));
        }
    }

    public void Show()  {
        Map<String, List<String>> rt = null;
        rt = getPartentChildPart("Gen");
        Build(rt);
    }
```

The result what I get this is

```
Gen
|-Test1
|-Test2
|-Test3
```

I don't understand why recursion is not working and how can I implement this... Although if I hardcode this it can work what if my tree grows in future then hard code will not work.

Comment: Can you not simply declare a static variable for your root which is returned when you use getSet()? Instead of creating a new tree everytime you need to get it.

Comment: But if I do it then, also I will not be able to get the whole tree.
If I do so, then also I will get this
```
Gen
|-Test1
|-Test2
|-Test3
```
but I required
```
Gen
|-Test1
|--Mat
|-Test2
|--123
|---Child's Child
|----Child's Child's Child
|----2406
|-Test3
|--24
```

Comment: Is there no way to get a child / the list of children?

Comment: getPartentChildPart() --> I can convert this method to give list of children.

For example, if I gave Gen as the parameter to getPartentChildPart() then it will return

List<Test1,Test2,Test3>


Make sure you see what the whole post.

Comment: I have seen the whole post, I'll add an answer based on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final TreeNode<String> struct = "Gen";

public void build(Map<String, List<String>> parentRoot, TreeNode<String> node)  {
        Map<String, List<String>> parent;
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> i : parentRoot.entrySet()) {
            for (Stringj : i.getValue()) {
                TreeNode<String> childNode = node.addChild(new TreeNode<>(j));
                parent = getPartentChildPart(j);
                build(parent, childNode);
               
            }
        }
    }

    
    public void show()  {
        Map<String, List<String>> ROOT = null;
        ROOT = getPartentChildPart("Gen");
        build(ROOT, struct);
        System.out.println(struct.display(struct));
    }
```

The mistake was that I need to create a new node every time and need to get the root outside the recurrsion.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do would be to add a method that returns your list of children. From there recursion becomes quite simple.

```
void itChildren(TreeNode<T> node)
{
   // do stuff

   if (!node.getChildren().isEmpty())
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildren().size(); i++)
      {
         itChildren(node.getChildren().get(i));
      }
   }

   // do stuff 
}
```

This would then iterate over the entirety of the tree. Depending on whether you want to do things before (which I believe is your case) or after the children you can place your code either at the top or bottom of the function.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Where should it be used in the build method or inside the TreeNode Implementation?

Comment: Inside the build method, or wherever you're printing your tree from. Probably what's best is to create a function independent of Build() which you call from Show().

Comment: getChildren should get me the List of the children of the parent! Am I right?